# Sign Qt applications on Mac with Developer ID

Tags: macos, qt, certificate, code-signing

I have a QT application that needs to be signed. Previously I used codesign utility on Mac to sign with certificates. With the release of mountain lion, Apple is forcing the developers to sign with the developer ID to avoid Gatekeeper warnings.

I found this blog article from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

It works only for the Xcode based project. I am using Qt creator and there is no proper documentation available for signing with Developer ID outside of the Xcode.

Has anyone run into the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://successfulsoftware.net/2012/08/30/how-to-sign-your-mac-os-x-app-for-gatekeeper/ you sign the Qt frameworks, plugins and the app bundle, e.g.:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: <yourID>" <yourApp>.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
```

etc.