# What is the fastest/easiest way - step by step, from the beginning - to "code sign" my Qt app on OS X so that it can be distributed?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, code-signing

I am writing a cross-platform app in Qt (using Qt Creator).  One of the target platforms is OS X.

The application is being packaged for installation on OS X by using the [BitRock Installer system](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) to create an `.app` file.

The application is intended for download and use by students and researchers in political science at various different colleges and universities.  (A download either from the App Store, or from a product website, is fine.)

I do not need iCloud or any other features associated with the App Store.  I just need to be able to distribute this application so that the warning (below) does not appear.

Currently the application is in an alpha-testing state - it is being tested by the product managers only.  I would nonetheless prefer to offer the product managers an installation package for OS X that does **not** present them with the following warning:

> The [installer application] can't be opened because it is from an
>   unidentified developer

(And, more importantly, when the application is released, I also don't want this warning to appear for end users.)

I understand that I need to prepare my application for distribution by [using an Apple Developer account and properly signing the application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I have created a developer account, and I am attempting to follow the steps in the link to sign my application and prepare it for distribution.

However, because the application is built in Qt, not Xcode, I do not know how to follow the steps through to completion, because some of the key steps assume that Xcode is being used.

I have searched for any questions that might describe how to prepare Qt applications on OS X for distribution, but come up empty.

(Further, I would also prefer to have a set of steps provided that is as simple as possible - preferably simpler than the steps provided in the above link - in any case.)

What is the simplest possible set of steps that will allow me to code sign my application, developed with Qt, on OS X, so that it can be distributed?

Comment: Does this page help at all? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW2

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Thanks for the link. (I already found that link, as well.)  If I do not receive an acceptable answer here, I will pursue that (and other) links.  I anticipate hours of work to learn the details sufficiently to make progress, if I proceed with that link.  I hope to receive an answer here that is more directly tuned to the specific set of steps required for my use-case.

Comment: Hours of work? I think you can just type `codesign my-identity my-app.app`, no? Do you have a signing identity? Also, what are the specifics of your use-case? Isn't it the same process for all files that need signing, regardless of whether or not they were developed with Qt?

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter It sounds like you have enough knowledge to post an answer.  If you have time, I'd appreciate it (and spell out in more detail the steps you've indicated in your comment - as I mention in my title, I'm looking for all steps, from the beginning; I am not experienced in packaging OS X applications for distribution, though I am an experienced C++ programmer).

Comment: AFAIK, the steps are just: Pay Apple 99 dollars to get a Developer ID, download certificate, insert its name into "my-identity" above

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Prepare `.app` file**

This is a step by step guide to create a signed package which can be uploaded to the Mac App Store, or distributed independently as a standalone application + installer:

- Check app icon - it should have all sizes (16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, 1024x1024).  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028483/368896)
- Add compile options for proper generation of debugging symbols:

  `QMAKE_CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -gdwarf-2`

  (noting that `QMAKE_CFLAGS` may not be highlighted by Qt Creator as valid, but still may need to be included - see [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16577))
- Settings should be saved in a directory with same name as bundle identifier.
- Check the application's Info.plist file. It should contain the correct bundle identifier and minimum MacOS X version of 10.6.6.

  (Note: though Qt Creator automatically generates a default info.plist file that is placed inside the `.app` bundle, it is also possible to create your own file and have this automatically used instead.  See [this link for a sample info.plist file that works with Qt and the App Store](http://kuvacode.com/francis/qt-and-the-mac-app-store/), and note that `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST` *does* work to use a custom file (see comments in that link).)

  (Also, see notes below about how to obtain a bundle identifier.)

  (The minimum OS X version - which should be set to 10.6.6 or later - can be set with the following line in the `.pro` file: `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6` - but if you use a custom `info.plist` file, this setting won't take effect, so you must include the proper setting in your custom `info.plist` anyways; see previous link for the entry that should be used in the file.)
- You also need certificates to sign your application and installer: open “Keychain Access” (use Mac OS X search) -> double click on each certificate (look in the `kind` column for these) and enter password -> check added certificates in Keychain Access.

**Register application in iTunesConnect**

- Log in to your developer account at http://itunesconnect.apple.com (which will reroute you to https://, but you may need to first enter http://)

  (Note: If you do not already have one, you must first create a Mac Developer Account, $99/year, in order to proceed.)
- Click on “Manage your apps” -> “Add new app”
- If application has no Bundle ID - create it.

> Creating a new Bundle ID is *not* intuitive.
>
> To create a new Bundle ID:
>
> -> Log in to the *Developer Center* website: This is a different site
>   (perhaps open it in a new tab): http://developer.apple.com.
>
> -> Click *Member Center* near the very top right (next to the search bar)
>
> -> Click on *Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles*
>   (underneath *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles*)
>
> -> Click on *App IDs* in the left navigation bar (in the *Identifiers* section)
>   (This might already be selected.)
>
> -> Click on + button
>
> -> The screen you now see (*Register Mac App ID* / *Registering an App ID*)
>   is the screen you use to create a new bundle identifier
>
> -> Enter the necessary information.  Write anything for the 
>   *App ID Description* (it can contain only a short line of text)
>
> The *Explicit App ID* field is actually the new Bundle ID.
>   Type a reverse URL here, such as `com.mydomain.myapp`.
>   A website or server does not actually need to exist at this URL.
>   You just make one up here, but of course you can use one that
>   already exists if you wish.
>
> -> Click *Continue*, then *Submit* if you're satisfied, then *Done*
>
> Now be sure to go back to the previous section, and add the Bundle ID you have just created to the custom `info.plist` file.
>
> Also save the **Team ID** in case you need it later - this is the string that precedes the Bundle > > ID (called the *prefix*) that you see when you look at the details of the Bundle ID you've just > > > created in the Developer Center.

- Now, go back to the iTunesConnect website.  (Perhaps in another tab - this is *not* the Developer Center website.)
- In the *App Information* section, select language. Then, enter app name.  Make up a random string of characters for the *SKU* field (I use something of the format *2436-7623-7782-8327*).  Finally, select the Bundle ID.  Click Continue.
- Select availability date (simply as far as possible, for now - currently, it's only possible to make it available for at most 2 years).  Select price tier (can be any - customer can change later).  Click Continue.
- Enter detailed application information on the following screen, and click Save.
- Click “View Details” in app page -> Click “Ready to upload binary” -> On summary page click on link “latest version of Application Loader” and download it -> Click “Continue”.

**Creating and Uploading installer**

- Check application Info.plist - enter right bundle id, app name, category.
- Build application in release mode.
- Extract debug symbols.  At the command line:

  `dsymutil MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -o MyApp.app.dSYM`
- Execute the helper program `macdeployqt` (included with Qt).  At the command line:

  `/path/to/macdeployqt /path/to/myapp.app`

  (`macdeployqt` can be found in `QTDIR/bin`.  See [this link](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#macdeploy) for a handful of official details.)

  Running `macdeployqt` modifies your existing application by incorporating the necessary Qt frameworks internal to the `.app` bundle and changing various other internal settings in the application.
- Codesign application:

> Codesigning is a tricky step.
>
> **(1) Obtaining a DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE**
>
> You must first create a Distribution certificate, if you don't already have one.  (*Not* a
>   Developer certificate.)
>
> (The following steps are taken from [this link](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=301), with a correction regarding the certificate
>   type)
>
> -> Open Xcode (version 5 as of this writing)
>   -> Navigate to Xcode > Preferences
>   -> Click the Accounts tab
>   -> If you have not already done so, add the Apple ID that is registered in the Mac Developer
>   Program
>   -> Select the Apple ID that you want to use, and click View Details
>   -> In the window that opens, click Add (+) and then select *Mac App Distribution*.
>
> **(2) Code signing the application with the Distribution Certificate**
>
> To properly codesign, *every* `.framework` and `.dylib` **inside the `.app` bundle** must **FIRST**
>   be signed; and then the `.app` itself must be signed.  **See critical steps in bottom paragraph of
>   this grey block before you codesign the internal Qt frameworks** - and be sure to do this first.
>
> The command to sign the internal libraries/frameworks, and the command to sign the main `.app`, 
>   is the same:
>
> **`codesign -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Daniel Nissenbaum (S6V5TT9QRL)" –-entitlements
>   MyEntitlements.plist MyApp.app`**
>
> **The *--entitlements MyEntitlements.plist* option is only necessary if you actually have 
>   entitlements beyond the basic
>   defaults.**  I (Dan Nissenbaum) did not select additional privileges for my app when I created the
>   Bundle ID in Developer Center (such as ability to access iCloud, push notifications, etc.). So, I
>   left off the *--entitlements* option, and I have not looked into how to obtain a
>   *MyEntitlements.plist* file.
>
> *Note regarding the -s argument*: See paragraph below for information about finding the correct
>   name to use (this is the Distribution Certificate "Common Name").
>
> This **codesign** command is for the main `.app`.  **To codesign the internal (Qt)
>   libraries/frameworks, 
>   which must be done *first*, use the proper path**; i.e., in the command above, use
>   **`MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework`** rather than **`MyApp.app`** - and note that 
>   the path to the libraries/frameworks must be just to the root of the internal library/framework 
>   bundle, not to *inside* the internal library/framework bundle.
>
> *Various other internal .dylibs or .frameworks may also need to be signed*, in addition to the
>   Qt .frameworks - if you try to sign your main application but have not
>   signed all of the internal *.dylibs/.frameworks*, you will receive an error indicating another
>   internal
>   *.dylib/.framework* that needs signing.  Just proceed through them all.  In my case, there were
>   about
>   10 additional *.dylibs* that needed to be signed after I completed signing the Qt *.frameworks*.
>
> Once you have the developer certificate, you need to find the name of the certificate for use with
>   the **codesign** process.  Open "Keychain Access" (to find this, simply type "Keychain Access" into
>   the Search bar in the Finder, and locate the application from among the results returned).  In the
>   main list that you see when Keychain Access runs, you will see your Developer certificate among
>   various other things.  There will also be some other certificates - ignore those.  It should be
>   obvious which certificate is the correct one.  In my case (which is standard, I assume), the 
>   certificate name is "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Daniel Nissenbaum (S6V5TT9QRL)". 
>   This is the official name of the certificate, to be
>   used as the **-s** argument to **codesign**, but to really confirm this, double-click on the 
>   certificate and in the info window that appears, have a look at the "Common Name".  **The value of
>   *Common Name* is the official text to use as the *-s* argument of *codesign*.**
>
> Note regarding a **complication with `codesign`'ing** the internal Qt frameworks.  As of today, 
>   when `macdeployqt` is run, the Qt frameworks are not fully copied correctly into the `.app` bundle.
>   They are missing their `Info.plist` file.  But these necessary `Info.plist` files *DO* exist inside
>   the Qt installation.  You can simply use the Finder to copy them.  (For example on my system, the 
>   required `Info.plist` file for the `QtWidgets.framework` framework has this path (where "Qt"
>   corresponds to the root path of your Qt installation):
>   **`Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Contents/Info.plist`.**  This is to be copied into 
>   **`MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Resources`**.  Ditto for all of the other Qt 
>   frameworks that were copied into the `MyApp.app` bundle by `macdeployqt`.  See 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639825/368896 for more details.exists and is enabled for code

- Create installer (**a different certificate is required; see comment**):

  `productbuild –-component ./MyApp.app /Applications –-sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Daniel Nissenbaum (S6V5TT9QRL)" MyApp.pkg`

  **Note that a different certificate is required to be used as the argument to the `--sign` parameter.**  The certificate has type "*Mac Installer Certificate*", rather than "*Mac App Distribution*" (the type of the certificate used with `codesign`, above).  To create this certificate, follow the same steps above, but select *Mac Installer Certificate* as the type.  Use its *Common Name* as the argument to the `--sign` parameter here.

  **The *./* preceeding the application name might be important**.  Also, use the same argument to the *--sign* parameter that you did when you ran *codesign* - the *Common Name* of your Developer certificate.  See above.
- Check the installer:

  `sudo installer -store -pkg MyApp.pkg -target /`
- If there are no errors, you now have a legitimate Mac application, packaged into a legitimate Mac installer, both of which can be distributed to anyone.  You can distribute them by simply sending them the `.pkg` file (via website, Dropbox, etc.), or you can upload to the Mac App Store.
- **I have not confirmed these steps**, which are for actually uploading the application to the Mac App Store: Open Application Loader and sign in with Apple Developer Account -> Select “Deliver Your App” -> Choose right AppID -> Click on “Choose…” button on “Application Information” page and select created pkg file -> Click “Send”.

**Additional information**

- [Information about entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html)
- [Information about Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)
- [Additional information about deploying app to Mac AppStore](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/04/03/how-to-publish-qt-applications-in-the-mac-app-store-2/)

Comment: This looks fantastic!  I will try this over the next couple of days and follow up.  Thanks.

Comment: Question: I am not all that familiar with `dwarf`.  Will the compiler flags cause the creation of some type of debug build that will slow performance?  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Debug symbols are always located in different sections from the code sections, so there are no performance drawbacks.

Comment: I've just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027988/how-to-set-the-application-icon-in-a-qt-application-on-os-x-sufficient-for-dist to try to figure out the very first step.

Comment: Are you certain that all sizes listed are required?  "*Check app icon - it should have all sizes (16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, 1024x1024).*" - in iConvert Icons (from your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028483/368896), the "Mac OS X 10.8+" option does NOT list 64x64 as available (but it does list all of the others).

Comment: A question regarding the 3rd bullet point in the top (`Prepare .app file`) section.  *Settings should be saved in a directory ...* - Which settings are you referring to?  Thanks.

Comment: (Also, for others who are novices to OS X application development: The `info.plist` file referenced in the steps above can be found inside the `.app` file representing your application.  Right-click the `.app` file and select `View Package Contents`.)

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum To be serious I'm not sure, but it's really easy to check during icns file creation in iConvert Icons. File created there won't be rejected in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

First, see [Sign Qt applications on Mac with Developer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653157/sign-qt-applications-on-mac-with-developer-id/13654967#13654967) and [Sign a Framework for OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637131/sign-a-framework-for-osx-10-9)

Basically,

1. compile your application
2. run `macdeployqt`
3. check using `otool -L ...` the dependencies of all your frameworks, libraries and plugins
4. use `install_name_tool -change ...` to change any dependencies not properly deployed to inside the bundle
5. sign your frameworks and bundle (see the 2 links given above)

You will need to pay Apple for a developer ID to be able to sign your application otherwise your users will have to deal with Gatekeeper.

Comment: Quick question - how does this set of steps compare to @TaylorBrandstetter's comment below my question (*download certificate, insert its name into "my-identity" above* - and his preceding comment)?  Are they equivalent?  Do you know if Taylor's answer will also work?  Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to use Xcode to download the developer certificate, but you don't need to use Xcode after that. My links show how to do the actual signing. Personally, I wrote a big clunky script to do steps 2-5. No, you can't just use "my-identity" in that command line and you have to sign all frameworks and libraries, not just the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please, check the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html)

As you wrote, you may distribute your application outside of the App Store. Such bundles or pkg installers should be signed with the Developer ID signing identity. This is the only signature that will pass checks by MacOS GateKeeper.

You must be a "Team Agent" to obtain this. If you are working alone this should be no problem for you. If you are not "Team Agent" you will need to create the certificate request and send it to your "Team Agent" who will generate the public key for you and send it back.

Once you will have a valid Developer ID signing identity (as people wrote in comments) you can just sign your app with similar command line command: codesign "Developer ID ...." myApplicationPath.app

P.S. Latest xCode provides a nice UI to obtain different types of signing identities. Just check the link at the top of answer.